# Android: IPC in Application class

Tags: android, ipc

I'm developing a multi-process Android app that needs to pass data between processes before any activity is created.

Ideally, I would like to intercept incoming Intent for an activity inside `Application.onCreate()`, however, I don't think there is any way to do that.

Does the Android Framework provide any inter-process communication options that are available from the `Application` class?

Comment: Does it really have to be before *any* activity is shown? If not then you could start a "launcher" activity which does the IPC and then navigates to the destination activity. When you call `finish()` inside the launcher activity it won't be shown.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it has to be before any `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.onActivityPreCreated()` is called and the activity stack is still empty.